# Python Pandas iterate over rows and access column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to iterate over the rows of a Python Pandas dataframe. Within each row of the dataframe, I am trying to to refer to each value along a row by its column name.

Here is what I have:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,4),columns=list('ABCD'))
print df
          A         B         C         D
0  0.351741  0.186022  0.238705  0.081457
1  0.950817  0.665594  0.671151  0.730102
2  0.727996  0.442725  0.658816  0.003515
3  0.155604  0.567044  0.943466  0.666576
4  0.056922  0.751562  0.135624  0.597252
5  0.577770  0.995546  0.984923  0.123392
6  0.121061  0.490894  0.134702  0.358296
7  0.895856  0.617628  0.722529  0.794110
8  0.611006  0.328815  0.395859  0.507364
9  0.616169  0.527488  0.186614  0.278792
```

I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16476974/4057186) to iterate, but it is only giving me part of the solution - **after selecting a row in each iteration, how do I access row elements by their column name?**

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print row.loc[0,'A']
    print row.A
    print row.index()
```

My understanding is that the row is a Pandas [series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html). But I have no way to index into the Series.

Is it possible to use column names while simultaneously iterating over rows?

Comment: `row` in your example is not a Series, it should be a tuple. But if you do `for idx, row in df.iterrows()`, `row['A']`  should work fine?

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thanks.

Comment: Most numeric operations with pandas can be vectorized - this means they are much faster than conventional iteration. OTOH, some operations (such as string and regex) are inherently hard to vectorize. This this case, it is important to understand _how_ to loop over your data. More more information on when and how looping over your data is to be done, please read [For loops with Pandas - When should I care?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care/54028200#54028200).

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I also like `itertuples()`

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    print(row.A)
    print(row.Index)
```

since row is a named tuples, if you meant to access values on each row this should be **MUCH** faster

speed run :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in range(1000*1000)], columns=['A'])
st=time.time()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row.A
print(time.time()-st)
45.05799984931946

st=time.time()
for row in df.itertuples():
    row.A
print(time.time() - st)
0.48400020599365234
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is actually what I had in mind (but could not remember). It is much more practical (since there is no need for `idx`, like having to `enumerate` a list). Since I asked for for `iterrows()`, I'll go with that answer. But this is what I would have used had I remembered.

Comment: `print(row.Index)` results in: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Index'`

Comment: @kiltek did you use `itertuples(index=False)` ? if not, i would need some code to figure out whats wrong

Comment: @WR This should be the accepted answer. It is [up to 50x faster](https://github.com/mm-mansour/Fast-Pandas).

Comment: As I understand it, if the number of columns is greater than 255, the tuples returned are not named. Is there any way to overwrite this and produce named tuples for ~3000 columns? I want to eventually grab those column names that meet a condition. @Steven G

Comment: @abbas786 sadly no, the 255 column limit is a `namedtuple` limit. not a pandas limit.

Answer (score 35):

The item from `iterrows()` is not a Series, but a tuple of (index, Series), so you can unpack the tuple in the for loop like so:

```
for (idx, row) in df.iterrows():
    print(row.loc['A'])
    print(row.A)
    print(row.index)

#0.890618586836
#0.890618586836
#Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: @StevenG Yeah. That's what I meant to say. I guess it's clearer if we say (index, Series).

Comment: use itertuples() as suggested in the second answer...If you are working with a large dataframe intertuples is a lot faster

Answer (score 32):

## How to iterate efficiently

If you really have to iterate a Pandas dataframe, you will probably want to **avoid using iterrows()**. There are different methods and the usual `iterrows()` is far from being the best. **itertuples() can be 100 times faster.**

**In short:**

- As a general rule, use `df.itertuples(name=None)`. In particular, when you have a fixed number columns and less than 255 columns. *See point (3)*
- Otherwise, use `df.itertuples()` except if your columns have special characters such as spaces or '-'. *See point (2)*
- It is possible to use `itertuples()` even if your dataframe has strange columns by using the last example. *See point (4)*
- Only use `iterrows()` if you cannot use the previous solutions. *See point (1)*

## Different methods to iterate over rows in a Pandas dataframe:

Generate a random dataframe with a million rows and 4 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(1000000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print(df)
```

1. The usual `iterrows()` is convenient, but damn slow:

   ```py
   start_time = time.clock()
   result = 0
   for _, row in df.iterrows():
       result += max(row['B'], row['C'])

   total_elapsed_time = round(time.clock() - start_time, 2)
   print("1. Iterrows done in {} seconds, result = {}".format(total_elapsed_time, result))
   ```
2. The default `itertuples()` is already much faster, but it doesn't work with column names such as `My Col-Name is very Strange` (you should avoid this method if your columns are repeated or if a column name cannot be simply converted to a Python variable name).:

   ```py
   start_time = time.clock()
   result = 0
   for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
       result += max(row.B, row.C)

   total_elapsed_time = round(time.clock() - start_time, 2)
   print("2. Named Itertuples done in {} seconds, result = {}".format(total_elapsed_time, result))
   ```
3. The default `itertuples()` using name=None is even faster but not really convenient as you have to define a variable per column.

   ```py
   start_time = time.clock()
   result = 0
   for(_, col1, col2, col3, col4) in df.itertuples(name=None):
       result += max(col2, col3)

   total_elapsed_time = round(time.clock() - start_time, 2)
   print("3. Itertuples done in {} seconds, result = {}".format(total_elapsed_time, result))
   ```
4. Finally, the named `itertuples()` is slower than the previous point, but you do not have to define a variable per column and it works with column names such as `My Col-Name is very Strange`.

   ```py
   start_time = time.clock()
   result = 0
   for row in df.itertuples(index=False):
       result += max(row[df.columns.get_loc('B')], row[df.columns.get_loc('C')])

   total_elapsed_time = round(time.clock() - start_time, 2)
   print("4. Polyvalent Itertuples working even with special characters in the column name done in {} seconds, result = {}".format(total_elapsed_time, result))
   ```

Output:

```
         A   B   C   D
0       41  63  42  23
1       54   9  24  65
2       15  34  10   9
3       39  94  82  97
4        4  88  79  54
...     ..  ..  ..  ..
999995  48  27   4  25
999996  16  51  34  28
999997   1  39  61  14
999998  66  51  27  70
999999  51  53  47  99

[1000000 rows x 4 columns]

1. Iterrows done in 104.96 seconds, result = 66151519
2. Named Itertuples done in 1.26 seconds, result = 66151519
3. Itertuples done in 0.94 seconds, result = 66151519
4. Polyvalent Itertuples working even with special characters in the column name done in 2.94 seconds, result = 66151519
```

[This article is a very interesting comparison between iterrows and itertuples](https://medium.com/swlh/why-pandas-itertuples-is-faster-than-iterrows-and-how-to-make-it-even-faster-bc50c0edd30d)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

This was not as straightforward as I would have hoped. You need to use enumerate to keep track of how many columns you have. Then use that counter to look up the name of the column. The accepted answer does not show you how to access the column names dynamically.

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=False, name=None):
    for k,v in enumerate(row):
        print("column: {0}".format(df.columns.values[k]))
        print("value: {0}".format(v)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
for i in range(1,len(na_rm.columns)):
           print ("column name:", na_rm.columns[i])
```

Output :

```
column name: seretide_price
column name: symbicort_mkt_shr
column name: symbicort_price
```

Comment: That is inneficient writing, and the for loop could iterate directly on the columns list.