# The role of the word "Value" in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to refer to paragraph 3 in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603068/writing-a-function-that-returns-and-prints-the-maximum-value-out-of-all-the-val), asking for the role of the word: `Value`.

Being more explicit, I'm talking about this code line:

```
print(df[['Gold']][df.Value == df.Value.max()])
```

Referring [the answer I've got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603068/writing-a-function-that-returns-and-prints-the-maximum-value-out-of-all-the-val?answertab=votes#tab-top),

I'm talking also about the role of the word: `Value` also in this snippet:

```
for value in df['Gold']:
    if value>CurrentMax:
        CurrentMax = value
```

And referring [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741759/find-maximum-value-of-a-column-and-return-the-corresponding-row-values-using-pan), in these code lines:

The following four (separated) code lines, in which it is written: `'Value'` (or `['Value']`), **with CAPITAL V**:

```
data.groupby(['Country','Place'])['Value'].max()

df.loc[df['Value'].idxmax()]

df[df['Value']==df['Value'].max()]

print '%s, %s, %s' % (s['Country'], s['Place'], s['Value'])
```

In this code line, in which it is written: `'value'` (or `['value']`), **with small v**:

```
df.groupby(['country','place'], as_index=False)['value'].max()
```

And in this code line, in which it is written **between dots and with small letters, without apostrophes**:

```
df.groupby("country").apply(lambda df:df.irow(df.value.argmax()))
```

**An important note:**

**I'm actually asking SEVERAL QUESTIONS here:**

1. Why are there differences in the way the word `Value` is written?
2. Is that word a function? A keyword? An attribute? Something else?
3. What is the word's role in each piece of code written above?

Just to distinguish, I was looking also at the `values()` function [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html),

and also searched the word `Value` in the [Pandas DataFrame Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html),

to check whether it was an attribute, a method or (maybe) something else.
I didn't find anything in this last document.

Thanks!

Comment: `Value` is a column in the dataframe. Pandas allows easy access to columns this way. Obviously, this only works for columns that don't share the name with existing dataframe attributes.

Comment: If it's written `value`, then the column is simply named without an initial `V`.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access

Comment: @9769953 Well, that's (a bit) long... but seems useful at the same time. :-) It may solve a big part of my question, seemingly. Thanks!