# How do I iterate over every value of a Pandas Series? (specific to problem mentioned in description)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

> Apologies for the title, I couldn't find a better way to frame my
>   question.

I have two columns df['c1'], df['c2']. I want to pass every value from both these columns into a *function* to get a result (for every row) and have this series of results as a new column df['c3'].

what I've tried:

```
df['c3'] = function(df['c1'], df['c2'])
```

Unfortunately I get ***TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'float'***

So how exactly do I iterate over every value of both the series (df['c1'], df['c2']) to produce my column df['c3'] ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619896/python-pandas-iterate-over-rows-and-access-column-names/43620031#43620031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
df["c3"] = df.apply(lambda row: function(row["c1"], row["c2"]), axis=1)
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a bunch!